How to disable the application overview when I snap windows to the side?
I recently updated my laptop from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 (with Gnome 46), which went without major issues. However, now when I try to "snap" windows to the left or right side of the screen, something strange happens; an application selector appears on the other half of the screen. In this first screenshot, you can see the beginning state; a Nautilus window over a Firefox browser.

In this second photo I took of my screen (I couldn't take a screenshot in that state), you see what happens when I press <SUPER KEY> + <RIGHT ARROW KEY>; the nautilus window snaps to the right (as expected), and on the left half of the screen a row of application icons appears.

I think the use of this is that I can select an application from this icon list for the left half of the screen. So I think it's a feature, not a bug. However, I think it's really annoying. Does anybody know how I can stop this functionality? I just want to snap a window, nothing else.
All tips are welcome!

Without a settings amendment (turn off Tile Groups), hit ESC once.

Ok nevermind. I found the answer. And it's quite simple. For others struggeling with the same. It's just a setting:

